# How to run my servo until an input is recieved?

Tags: sensors, servo

I am VERY new to this so please excuse any silly questions.

I am trying to run an FS90 micro servo in a sweeping motion until I receive a certain value from my Adafruit TCS34725 colour sensor. I currently have my loop set that it checks the colour sensor red value using an if statement and then performs a single sweep and then checks again. Rinse Repeat. Is there a way I can get it to check the sensor and stop mid sweep if there is a red colour change?

Comment: I guess, that you use `delay()` in your for loop. Instead of the blocking `delay()` call use a non-blocking coding style like in the `BlinkWithoutDelay` example, that comes with the Arduino IDE. It uses `millis()` as clock and checks, wether a specific time period has passed. If yes, it does what it needs to do, if not, it will exit fast to execute different code, until it is time to do something.

Comment: Please show us the sketch you're using.